# D3 Tree Diagram Curved Line Start Position

Tags: javascript, d3.js, projection

**Summary**

Using the example below I've created a database driven tree view with blocks of information instead of the circle nodes.

[Interactive d3.js tree diagram](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092)

Please see the example screenshot below:

[image: Example image of block nodes]

The idea is for the lines to start from where the block ends. I assume it's something to do with the following function:

```
// Custom projection
var linkProjection = d3.svg.diagonal()
   .source(function (d) {
       return { "y": d.source.y, "x": d.source.x };
   })
   .target(function (d) {
       return { "y": d.target.y, "x": d.target.x };
   })
   .projection(function (d) {
       return [d.y, d.x];
   });

// Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
link.enter().insert("path", "g")
   .attr("class", "link")
   .style("fill", "none")
   .style("stroke", "#d1d6da")
   .style("stroke-width", "1")
   .attr("d", function (d) {
       var s = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 };
       var t = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 };
       return linkProjection({ source: s, target: t });
});
```

I have tried adding the block width to the y coordinate but although it starts from the correct position with the drawing it ends at the start of the block again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess its somewhere in this code  var s = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 }; the x coordinate If You share your code then It shall help

Answer (score 0):

Without more code it's hard to say, but I think it has to do with the coordinate system. x,y point to the center of the object I think. So you'll have to translate y to the the right by half the length of your box.

i.e. The parents previous position (x,y) points to the center of the parent.

Comment: Ok, I have added a CodePen for the example. The concept is the same, the lines should start on the edge of the circle and not from the center.

[link]http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLKVaM